# How to merge two array object dynamically in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have two array something like this

```
array1 = [
    {
        Name: "BMW car",
        id: "BMW",
        group: "car",
        children: [
            { Name: "320 Mod", id: "320", group: "BMW" },
            { Name: "X3 Mod", id: "X3", group: "BMW" },
            { Name: "X5 Mod", id: "X5", group: "BMW" }
        ]
    }
];

array2 = [
    {
        id: "BMW",
        description: "parent car BMW",
        children: [
            { id: "320", description: "parent car BMW, model 320", },
            { id: "X3", description: "parent car BMW model X3", },
            { id: "X5", description: "parent car BMW Model X5", }
        ]
    }
];
```

The result array should be something like this below

```
arrayObj = [
    {
        Name: "BMW car",
        id: "BMW",
        group: "car",
        description: "parent car BMW",
        children: [
            { Name: "320 Mod", id: "320", group: "BMW", description: "parent car BMW model 320", },
            { Name: "X3 Mod", id: "X3", group: "BMW", description: "parent car BMW model X3", },
            { Name: "X5 Mod", id: "X5", group: "BMW", description: "parent car BMW model X5", }
        ]
    }
];
```

I have tried below code but the children value doesn't get merged. Can any one please help me

```
var resultArray = array1.reduce((arr, e) => {
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, e, array2.find(a => a.id == e.id)))
    return arr;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```js
var array1 = [
    {
        Name: "BMW car",
        id: "BMW",
        group: "car",
        children: [
            { Name: "320 Mod", id: "320", group: "BMW" },
            { Name: "X3 Mod", id: "X3", group: "BMW" },
            { Name: "X5 Mod", id: "X5", group: "BMW" }
        ]
    }
];

var array2 = [
    {
        id: "BMW",
        description: "parent car BMW",
        children: [
            { id: "320", description: "parent car BMW, model 320", },
            { id: "X3", description: "parent car BMW model X3", },
            { id: "X5", description: "parent car BMW Model X5", }
        ]
    }
];

var result = array1.map(el1 => {
  var el2 = array2.find(el => el1.id === el.id);
  return { ...el1, ...el2, children: el1.children.map(child1 => ({ ...child1, ...el2.children.find(child2 => child2.id === child1.id) })) };
});

console.log(result);
```